# Can't find the role of allowFormAuthenticationForClients parameter in AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer - Spring OAuth

Tags: spring-oauth2

What is `allowFormAuthenticationForClients` parameter of class `org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer` for.

I've searched in spring **Oauth** documentation and also spring API and there is no description about this parameter ( by default it's sets to false).

Answer (score 1):

This is a the security constraints on the TOKEN ENDPOINT(ex. oauth/token).

Spring's documantation said;

> The token endpoint is protected for you by default by Spring OAuth in the @Configuration support using HTTP Basic authentication of the client secret.

The `allowFormAuthenticationForClients` parameter set to true means that it is protected using basic authentication and form authentication.